# Relationship between the Poisson distribution and Binomial

Tags: binomial-distribution, poisson-process

I don't know exactly how to explain this, but if you have say N independent binary outcomes (say, 50 bits, where each bit is either on or off), and thus the probability distributions $p_{\text{i}}(x_{\text{i}}|y)$ are binomial, if you take the average probability $p_{x = 1}(y)$, you get something like the expected proportion of bits that are on for a given y. Considering all trials are independent, if we further assume a bit can be in only one state at any given instant time point t, if you multiply the average probability by the number of bits (50) and you round that product to the greatest integer lesser/equal to it, isn't that basically a (homogeneous) Poisson process?

Edit: In short, if you have N independent trials modelled by a binomial distribution, could the system taken as a whole be modelled as Poisson process?

Comment: You’re confusing a Poisson Process: which occurs in continuous time, within the Poisson distribution, which is a discrete distribution.  Yes, there is a sense in which the Poisson distribution is the limit of a binomial distribution as $n$ goes to infinity and $np$ is held constant.

Comment: My apologies, I was mostly referring to the Poisson process. The reason I'm asking is because I have a number of conditional per-bit Binomial distributions of the form I mentioned above, but also a distribution averaged over all of the (equal) per-bit distributions, and I have a feeling like this average distribution is probably equal to $P_1(t)$ of a Poisson process.